# ¿Cómo crear un sistema de multidivisas/divisas PHP/MYSQLI/Ajax?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, mysqli

Tengo una tabla en la base de datos llamada: **divisa** la cual conforma de esta manera:

`id   moneda   precio  id_producto
 1     USD      100        1
 2     EUR      120        1`

La tabla de **productos**

`id_producto   producto   discrepcion   imagen     active
     1          laptop     nuevo       laptop.jpg    1
     2          phone      nuevo       phone.jpg     1`

Como obtengo el precio de la tabla **divisa** pero yo quiero mostrar al usuario la opción de escoger su moneda en un formulario `<select></select>` ahora cualquier moneda que fuera a seleccionar este valor se muestre en todas las páginas al mostrar los productos, al mostrar el detalle del producto, al añadir al carrito de compras con una `session` en `PHP` y una `cookie` para que guarde esta session de la moneda escogida la cookie que venza en 10 días y que se destruya la cookie si es que el usuario vuelve a seleccionar otra moneda.

Ahora no se si estaría bien implementar ajax para evitar recargar la pagina o aquel valor redireccionar a una página divisa.php y que esta página guarde el dato y se redirecione nuevamente a la url donde se selecciono la moneda. Similar a un updatecart.php en un updatecart.php se actualiza la cantidad de un producto y se añade un producto al carrito de compras ahora en la divisa.php se podría implementar algo parecido?

```
function newpro(){
    global $con;
    $sqlnew = "Select * from productos where id_producto and active='1' order by id desc limit 12";
    $rows = mysqli_query($con, $sqlnew);
    $new_products = mysqli_num_rows($rows);

    if($new_products==0){
        echo"No hay productos nuevos";
    }else{
        while ($newpro = mysqli_fetch_array($rows)) {
            echo'<div id="cont-items">
                <div class="image-items">
                <img src="'.$newpro['imagen'].'" height="10" width="150" alt="" />
                </div>
                     <div class="name-items">'.$newpro['producto'].'</div>
                 </div>
            ';
        }
    }
}
```

No se como plantear este sistema no entiendo muy bien sobre las cookie espero su respuesta ante mano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a poner un ejemplo muy simple, que tengo en funcionamiento y funcione perfectamente.

Simplemente creando una `cookie` para cada divesa que uno quiera añadir.
Asi evitamos tener que insertar a nuestra `Base Datos` cada divesa, algo tener en cuenta, que para calcular el valor de la divesa, esta se actualiza frecuentemente. Existen muchas paginas online, para saber este valor (https://es.finance.yahoo.com/divisas/conversor/#from=EUR;to=USD;amt=1)

Comenzamos donde el usuario selecciona la moneda deseada, pondre como ejemplo solo dos monedas, se podria ampliar facilmente:

```
<form method="POST" id="slc_moneda" enctype="text/plain">

    <input id="euro" type="radio" name="moneda" value="euro">
    <input id="dolar" type="radio" name="moneda" value="dolar">

    <button type="submit">Guardar cambios</button>
</form>

<div class="resultado"><!-- Mensajes PHP --></div>
```

Comenzamos con `Ajax`, este lo puedes incluir en el `<head></head>`, donde insertamos nuestro formulario.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', '#slc_moneda', function() {

        var data = $(this).serialize(); 

        $.ajax({    
            type : 'POST',
            url  : '.php/control_moneda.php',
            data : data,
            success :  function(data) { 
                $(".resultado").html(data);                              
            }
        });    
        return false; 

    });
});
```

Veamos como se nos queda la pagina `PHP` llamado por `Ajax`

```
<?php 
//Reseteo.
$moneda = $message = "";

//Verdadero -> Formulario
if (isset($_POST)) {

    //Comprobacion datos obligatorios.
    if (empty($_POST['moneda'])) {
        $message = "Selecciona una moneda para continuar.";
    } else { $moneda = dataFields($_POST['moneda'] ?: ''); }

    //Si se ha seleccionado una moneda.
    if ($moneda) {          

        if ($moneda == "euro") {
            //Destruimos cookie dolar, si esta definido.
            if (isset($_COOKIE['moneda_dolar'])) {
                setcookie("moneda_dolar",$moneda,1,"/",false, false);
            }
            //Activamos cookie euro
            setcookie("moneda_euro",$moneda,strtotime( '+365 days' ),"/",false, false);
            //Recargamos pagina
            echo "<script>window.location.reload();</script>";  
            $moneda = "";

        } elseif ($moneda == "dolar") {
            //Destruimos cookie euro, si esta definido.
            if (isset($_COOKIE['moneda_euro'])) {                   
                setcookie("moneda_euro",$moneda,1,"/",false, false);
            }
            //Activamos cookie dolar
            setcookie("moneda_dolar",$moneda,strtotime( '+365 days' ),"/",false, false);
            //Recargamos pagina         
            echo "<script>window.location.reload();</script>";  
            $moneda = "";

        } else { 
            $moneda = "";
            $message = "Ocurri&oacute; un error inesperado, int&eacute;ntelo de nuevo m&aacute;s tarde.

        }

    }

} 

//Function -> Obtenemos la moneda de manera segura.
function dataFields($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

//Salida Errores -> mensajes
echo $message;  
?>
```

Con este codigo ya creamos la moneda para el usuario durante 365 dias, y asi podra navegar comadamente, sin tener que seleccionar cada vez que visita tu web una moneda.

Te dejo tambien el ejemplo, como podrias visualizar los precios segun la `COOKIE`, la genero en una funcion, asi donde deseas mostrar el precio llamas a la función, asi puedes modificar rapidamente el valor actualizado en tu funcion, y no tener que modificarlo en cada pagina que añades el precio.

```
<?php //Mostramos el precio segun COOKIE (euro/dolar).

    function valorProducto() {

        global $precio;//Obtenido por Base de Datos.

        // EURO / USD (10 oct 2016)
        $valor_divisa_usd = 1,114;   
        //Aqui añadimos el valor de las divesas a calcular, en este caso solo voy a calcular de euro / dolar.

        if ( isset($_COOKIE['moneda_dolar'])) {                 

            // Calculamos el precio euro a dolar, simplemente multiplicando por el valor de la divesa añadido.
            $precio_dolar = $precio * $valor_divisa_usd;

            //Funcion php - convertor a USD
            setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
            $precio_dolar = money_format('%i', $precio_dolar) . "\n";                                       
            echo "$precio_dolar"; 

        } elseif (isset($_COOKIE['moneda_euro'])) {
            //Funcion php - convertor a EURO
            setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'es_ES');                                        
            $precio = money_format('%.2n', $precio) . "\n"; //devuelve 12.345,67 €
            echo "$precio"; 
        } else { //Por defecto
                //Funcion php - convertor a EURO
                setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'es_ES');                                        
                $precio = money_format('%.2n', $precio) . "\n"; //devuelve 12.345,67 €
            echo "$precio";  
        }
    }//Fin.
    ?>
```

> **Nota:** La función `money_format()` sólo está definida si el sistema tiene capacidad `strfmon`. Por ejemplo, **Windows** no lo hace, así que `money_format()` no está definido en **Windows**.

¡Suerte!

Answer (score 2):

Creo que una solución más eficiente es almacenar en la base de datos un valor base en una moneda, en dólares americanos por ejemplo, y almacenar las razones de cambio. Por ejemplo dólar-euro podría valer 0.8. Si deseas obtener el cambio de euro a dólar simplemente haces lo siguiente:

```
8 euros /0.8 = 10 dólares
```

Si deseas pasar de dólares a euros simplemente multiplicas por 0.8, tendrías algo como lo siguiente:

```
10 dólares * 0.8 = 8 euros
```

De esta forma no tienes que almacenar los valores valores de las divisas (en el supuesto de que tengas 20 divisas y 10 productos tendrías 200 valores en la base de datos, en cambio con lo anterior sólo almacenas 20 registros)

Para hacer el cambio de divisa, ejecutarías una llamada AJAX escrita en un archivo JS que se ejecuta al presionar un botón. El código podría ser algo parecido a esto:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", //o GET según necesites
        url: "api/divisas_api/get_us-mx", //la url de la función para consultar la razón de cambio
        data: {
            producto:"zapatos MVC-3421"
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('#precio').val()=data; // si estás usando un input 
$('#precio').append(data); // si estás escribiendo el precio como texto
        }});
```

Comment: En la manera que indicas me evita crear muchos registros, pero amigo estoy intentando crear el sistema no tengo creado nada aún si no es mucho pedir amigo podrías implementar un ejemplo completo por favor, ahora con el ejemplo que indicas como debo estructurar las tablas en la base de datos el precio lo debo incluir en la tabla productos y la consulta para mostrar los registro como debe ser y el ejemplo que indicas debe ser por medio de sesiones verdad para cuando yo desee implementar una paginación no se vaya a perder el valor.

Comment: No necesitas una sesión para tu propósito, el problema es que necesitas actualizar los precios de los productos a la nueva divisa ... con el código AJAX que escribi puedes hacer la consulta y la actualización al código HTML.

Si estás usando un framework MVC puedes crear una función (modelo) que tenga escrito el query y que ejecute la operación aritmética y la regrese, lo anterior es el parámetro URL en la respuesta.